# Embedding Webview in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I want to redirect on webview in Phonegap Project

The Android code is like this

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"uname\").value = '"
+ user 
+ "';" 
+ "document.getElementById(\"upwd\").value='" 
+ pwd 
+ "';" 
+ "document.getElementById(\"android_btn\").click();");
```

I want phonegap code please help me ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using inappbrowser plugin in phonegap [Inappbrowser Plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html)
The InAppBrowser is a web browser that displays in the app when calling window.open.

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```